# Recalculate values in MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web application that stores `points` in a table, and total points in the `user` table as below:

```
User Table
user_id | total_points

Points Table
id | date | user_id | points
```

Every time a user earns a point, the following steps occur:

```
1. Enter points value to points table
2. Calculate SUM of the points for that user
3. Update the user table with the new SUM of points (total_points)
```

The values in the user table might get out of sync with the sum in the points table, and I want to be able to recalculate the SUM of all points for every user once in a while (eg. once a month). I could write a PHP script that could loop through each user in the user table and find the sum for that user and update the total_points, but that would be a lot of SQL queries.

Is there a better(efficient) way of doing what I am trying to do? 
Thanks...

Comment: Can't you use mysql after insert trigger to update the user table?

Comment: I don't have a mysql trigger, but have a function in php code that acts like a trigger. The problem is, sometimes I manually delete rows from the points table from the database. I need to make a provision to delete points from the web app which calculates the sum again, but its too late now :P

Comment: Which version of mysql you use? MySQL Trigger is very usefur rather than PHP Code. You can create insert, update, delete trigger on points table to update user table. It will far better than PHP Code

Comment: Using trigger you can sync both table.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way to do this would be the following:

```
User Table
user_id

Points Table
id | date | user_id | points

Total Points View
user_id | total_points
```

A view is effectively a select statement disguised as a table. The select statement would be: `SELECT "user_id", SUM("points") AS "total_points" FROM "Points Table" GROUP BY "user_id"`. To create a view, execute `CREATE VIEW "Total Points View" AS <SELECT STATEMENT>` where `SELECT STATEMENT` is the previous select statement.

Once the view has been created, you can treat it as you would any regular table.

P.S.: I don't know that the quotes are necessary unless your table names actually contain spaces, but it's been a while since I worked with MySQL, so I don't remember it's idiosyncrasies.

Comment: Thanks. What SQL statement would I use to copy the total_points value from the total_points view to the user table? Can I do it in one single SQL query?

Comment: I would suggest not copying it to the user table. You can rework the Select statement to return any and all columns you want. The relational database way is to store data like points and user info in two separate tables and never have them in the same table. That said, to update as soon as the points table is modified, triggers are your best option. To update periodically, an update script and a [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But this time, I can't afford to restructure the tables. I just need to get the updated values for just this one time, since I have deleted some points manually. I need to update the user table with the correct total points.

Answer (score 2):

You have to user Triggers for this, to make the users total points in sync with the `user_points` table. Something like:

```
Create Trigger UpdateUserTotalPoints AFTER INSERT ON points
FOR EACH ROW Begin
    UPDATE users u
    INNER JOIN 
    (
       SELECT user_id, SUM(points) totalPoints
       FROM points
      GROUP BY user_id
    ) p ON u.user_id = p.user_id
   SET u.total_points = p.totalPoints;
END;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b253c/1)

**Note that:** As noted by @FireLizzard, if these records in the second table, are frequently updated or delted, you have to have other `AFTER UPDATE` and `AFTER DELETE` triggers as well, to keep the two tables in sync. And in this case the solution that @FireLizzard will be better in this case.

Comment: You could also create a trigger for `after delete` and `after update`

Comment: @FireLizzard - Good point. Yes, to keep the talbes in sync there must be `after delete` and `after update` but this is needed only if the second table is updated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it once a month, you can’t deal with just MySQL. You have too « logic » code here, and put too logic in database is not the correct way to go. The trigger of Karan Punamiya could be nice, but it will update the user_table on every insert in points table, and it’s not what you seem to want.

For the fact you want to be able to remove points, just add bsarv new negated rows in points, don’t remove any row (it will break the history trace).

If you really want it periodically, you can run a cron script that does that, or even call your PHP script ;)